# Reg expression to get a string starting from particular string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression which returns a string after a particular string.

For example:
The string is

```
"<https://meraki/api/v1/sm/devices?fields%5B%5D=imei%2Ciccid%2ClastConnected%2CownerEmail%2C+ownerUsername%2CphoneNumber&perPage=1000&startingAfter=0>; rel=first"
```

result I'm expecting is -- `first`.

Here is the expression i'm using

```
(?<=rel=\s").*(?=\)
```

Comment: What regex type are you using? Can you also elebarote a little bit more on what you want to get?

Comment: I need to parse a link value . I have converted this link value to a string .                                                        
Im expecting the output string value as " string after the rel=" in the link. which should be first.

Comment: Do you need everything after rel=" or just the attribute value?

Comment: @user okay, I think I understand. I assume you are using JS regex?

Comment: I need the attribute value. yes im using JS regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so this should work:

```
(?<=rel[=])[^"]*
```

I would advise looking over the syntax of regex again, because yours was not even matching the colons correctly. Look behinds `(?<=pattern)` match before the pattern you want to capture. Likewise look aheads `(?=pattern)` match after the pattern.

You can test your regex online [here](https://regexr.com/) (or many other sites). They will show you the matching groups and errors, but will also explain what certain parts of the pattern do.